# Increased disk space not visible to guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I've increased the size of a `Dynamically allocated storage` using `VBoxManage modifyhd [VDI] --resize 10240`. The guest OS is Ubuntu and the host is Win 7. According to Virtual Box the virtual size is 10.00 GB and Actual size is 5.83 GB. I booted with a live `GParted` CD to extend the volume, but it was already fully allocated. In the guest OS it looks like this.

[image: Screen shot of GParted and Diskspace]

Any suggestions why the increased size is not picked up in the guest OS?

Comment: Does the VM have a snapshot? If so, you probably didn't modify the size of the snapshot but just of the base VM.

Comment: Did you enlarge the filesystem yet? You’ll have to open the LUKS partition first.

Comment: @DanielB How do I open the LUKS partition?

Answer (score 0):

The guest OS can not detect new added space because you have only extended space of root vdi, vmdi. You have to extended space of snapshots also, so to extended space of snapshots execute following command in vm directory:

```
for x in Snapshots/*.vdi ; do VBoxManage modifyhd $x --resize 44960 ; done
```